# Rails DRY global variable/functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whats the best approach to keep a block of code DRY where its used across multiple controllers in a rails app?

For example, I have a call on an api that when called does sums/calculations based on start and end date variables. Each controller will do the same calculation, except for the start and end date which will be different per controller.

Would it be best to create something like a global variable/function to handle this and place it in my `application_controller` and pass the require variables via the controller?

```
data = HTTParty.get("https://www.url.com/start=#{@contoller.start_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}&finish=#{@contoller.end_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}&format=json")
@data = JSON.parse(data.body)
  
rainfall_total = 0
  
@data['data'].each do |data|
 # This adds up rainfall between above date variables
 rainfall = data['value'][0]
 @total_rain = (rainfall_total += rainfall).round(1)
end
```

So in the above code I have a start and end date variable. I have 3 controllers (stageOne, stageTwo and stageThree), in which different start/end date are inputted and it will calculate the total rainfall for each stage. What's best practice in regards to not repeating the same code in all three controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a service object to handle this request for you.

Your controllers should not be responsible for handling business logic like this, so you should be deferring to another object (Model, Service, etc) which should have this responsibility.

[This blog post provides some good examples](https://blog.engineyard.com/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services)

Essentially, you'd handle it like this:

*Create a file `app/services/rainfall_service.rb`*

```
class RainfallService
  def initialize(start_date, end_date)
    @start_date = start_date
    @end_date = end_date
  end

  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def call
    # TODO: implement your code for fetching the data, formatting it, etc
    # return the data you want to use
  end
end
```

Now, in your controllers you can just use your service to fetch your rainfall data wherever you need it:

*`app/controllers/stage_one_controller.rb`*

```
def show
  @rainfall = RainfallService.call(start_date, end_date)
end
```

I'm guessing your start/end dates will either come from `params` or something.

Hopefully that gives you the general idea.